# Guardar vários valores em um array

Tags: php

Boas, Tenho uma duvida em como poder guardar vários valores em um único array. Tenho o seguinte código que retorna o id da secção .

```
`$seccaoid = $prod['id_seccao'] = findIDByDescricao($arraySeccaoProduto[$i]);
save('amostras_custos', $prod);`
```

Isto faz com que me mostre o id do $arraySeccaoProduto[$i].

Por exemplo:

```
SECCAO----------------------------ID

findIDByDescricao(SECCAOa)----------1

findIDByDescricao(SECCAOc)----------3

findIDByDescricao(SECCAOd)----------4

findIDByDescricao(SECCAOb)----------2
```

Eu pretendia que no final de percorrer todos os $arraySeccaoProduto[$i] pegasse em todos os ids e guardasse assim:

```
$ids=[1;3;4;2]
```

Comment: Vê [aqui](https://www.portugal-a-programar.pt/forums/topic/43653-preencher-array/) se te ajuda, na parte: "Agora um exemplo de preenchimento de um array".

Comment: Como essa publicação ganhou um upvote? Não dá para entender o que o AP quer fazer, não há um [mcve], o AP citou vagamente elementos duma estrutura de dados indeterminada, nenhum do exemplo métodos tem o funcionamento claramente conhecido. Favor ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score -2):

Para guardar diversos valores em um mesmo array tem 2 opções.
Utilizar a função array_push().
Ou utilizar $arr[] = $var.

Doc: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-push.php

Acredito que você precise utilizar algo mais ou menos assim:

```
<?php

$arrId = [1,2,3,4,5];

function findIDByDescricao($id)
{
    return $id;
}

for($i=1; $i <= count($arrId); $i++)
{
    $prod['id_seccao'][] = findIDByDescricao($i);
}

print_r($prod);

?>
```

A Saída ficou assim:

```
Array
(
    [id_seccao] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
            [4] => 5
        )

)
```